# Repeat the same process on my script for different files

Tags: batch-file

I created a script to perform a number of actions on specific files. There are parameters to perform those specific actions to files with name `%filename%`. I'd like to be able to add more than one file at once. Any ideas?

```
set /p filename=Enter database to replace:

move /y "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%filename%.CHR" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"

move /y "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%filename%.HED" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"

move /y "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%filename%.PRD" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"

move /y "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%filename%.IDX" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"

move /y "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%filename%.INF" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"

move /y "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%filename%.TAD" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"

del \\enterprise\INFACT\INFACTCP\LOG\%filename%.CHK

copy "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT\%filename%.HED" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT\%~1.NEW"
```

I'd like to be able to add more than one value to be replaced by `%filename%`. Let's suppose that when I'm prompted *Enter the database to replace*, I could add `ABC`, `ABC1` and the process would be performed individually for all files named `ABC` and `ABC1`.

Answer (score 1):

use a `for` loop to disassemble your string:

```
set /p "filename=database(s)? "
for %%a in (%filename%) do (
  echo "\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT\%%~a.CHR" "\\enterprise\INFACTPR\CLIENT"
)
```

Try with `hello world` or `simple "two words"`

Comment: Hi! How that would work? I tried but it failed. How would I have to separate both files on the command line when prompted?

Comment: `name1 name2` as simple as that.

Comment: separate them with a space (use quotes, when the space should be part of the name). Note: I just echoed the strings. You'll have to replace `echo` with `move /y` to actually rename the files

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "clientdir=\\enterprise\INFACTCP\CLIENT"
set "newfilename=%~1"

set /p "fileset=Enter database to replace: " || exit /b 0

for %%A in (%fileset%) do (
    for %%B in (CHR HED PRD IDX INF TAD) do (
        if "%%~B" == "HED" if defined newfilename (
            copy "%clientdir%\%%~A.%%~B" "%clientdir%\%newfilename%.NEW"
        )
        move /y "%clientdir%\%%~A.%%~B" "%clientdir%\"
    )
    del "\\enterprise\INFACT\INFACTCP\LOG\%%~A.CHK"
)
```

At the input prompt, you can enter names i.e. `card "my book" chain key`.
That is the names of `card`, `my book`, `chain` and `key` with the double
quotes stripped from them. If nothing is entered, the script will exit,
by the use of `exit /b 0`.

The 1st `for` loop will set each name to `%%A`. The 2nd nested `for` loop
will set `%%B` to each extension. The extension `HED` needs to be copied
before it is moved, else it will not exist for the copy, so it is copied
before any move operation happens. The filename with `CHK` extension will
be deleted. The loops will continue until the file set has all been done.

View `for /?` about a file set (*set*) which is at the very top.